# How to visualize boxplot for full column and per categories

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I want to have a multiple boxplot for my Pandas DataFrame with different boxes for `num_column` per each category levels in `cat_column` AND one box for the entire `num_column`. So far the best that I could do is double subplots (one for the entire column and one for the per category boxes):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.subplots(1, 2)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
sns.boxplot(data=df, y="num_column")
plt.title("Full Column")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="cat_column", y="num_column")
plt.title("Categories")

plt.show()
```

I would like to have all in one plot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subplots, set number plot and use ax:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(18, 20))
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 0.8, wspace = 0.3)

sns.boxplot(data=df, x="price", y="squareMeters", ax=ax[0,0])
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="price", y="numberOfRooms", ax=ax[0,1])
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="hasYard", y="price", ax=ax[0,2])

sns.boxplot(data=df, x="hasPool", y="price", ax=ax[1,0])
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="price", y="floors", ax=ax[1,1])
sns.boxplot(data=df, x="price", y="cityCode", ax=ax[1,2])
```

x and y axis can read one column.